# Java Swing: Separation of logic and GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I made a program for Recommender System in Java. Now In order to make it more interactive, I want to provide a GUI wherever helpful.
For example: To display or edit the data file.

However, Java Swing asks for an event driven approach, which makes it more difficult to clearly separate the logic of the program from the GUI.

Can anyone suggest me an alternative to Swing, an alternative to more flexible GUI environment which could be used for a Java program?

Comment: Are you able to be more specific with the sort of things/data you want your GUI to show/edit?

Comment: As long as you keep your business logic in a separate class (oblivious to the exact GUI implementation) and just use its methods from your GUI calls, you should be decoupled enough to change either part without impacting the other.

Comment: @user2777005 its a CSV file which is want to convert into editable JTable and convert it back to CSV

Comment: I would recommend using something like apache poi to read the data from Excel into the arrays(I think) required to create a JTable

Answer (score 0):

Swing is flexible and if you follow proper design rules you can easily separate (via a Controller) GUI code (View) and application logic (Model).

Look up the [MVC pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm)